# How to build QJson under Windows for use with QtCreator?

Tags: windows, json, qt, qt-creator, qjson

I would like to know how to build QJson under Windows. I've downloaded sources, but I have no idea how to proceed with it. There are multiple instructions how to add a DLL from QJson, but how to I get the library file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The build instructions specific to Windows are [here](http://qjson.sourceforge.net/get_it/windows.html).